# Previously implemented goes missing after few builds ..Testing

Tags: testing, manual-testing

Say there are 1-10 user stories. All tested okay. -> to Production. Then comes the CR with 5 more user stories. All then tested okay. -> to production.
Then comes 5 more user stories. Tested okay. -> To production.. now here a user story or two from first 1- 10 breaks down. Obviously testers will have to carry the blame for the same.
Developers have direct access to the QA environments' build path. any developer can go put the code file there. just a simple folder structure.
How do we fix this and keep 'our' hands clean?
Also Please note that we do ad-hoc testing due to the stringent timelines.

Comment: Which types of test do you do? Only functional tests for US? Do you plan and do regression tests? Do you have separate environments for developers and testers? Do you have pre-prod environment?

Answer (score 0):

The situation when something new breaks down something old is rather common. I cannot see what is the problem. QA environment is perfectly good for catching up such a regression.

What i can suggest is:

**1. Having Development / QA / Production environments**

And try to set up the proper process of *if sth new has been coded up and developer-tested* it can go to '*QA*'. And only when the new stuff has been QA-tested it can go to '*Production*';

**2. Continuous Build Integration**

It's also nice to have the key features covered with the unit tests or (and) to have a suite of automated tests. One button-click can show you the general state of your app and even whose check-in has failed the build.

**3. Regression testing**

Ensure you have a profound Regression suite. These are run mainly to avoid such problems and verify that no critical issues leak into the production.

Hope this helps a little.